# Separating dotted lines from other image artifacts

Tags: python, opencv

I am starting out with medical images and I have managed to remove the entire background image.  Here is an example image after I have performed the processing steps so far:

[image]

My goal is to separate the dotted lines from the rest of the artifacts my current processing steps haven't yet removed.  Could someone point me in a good direction to completely separate these dotted lines from the rest of the image?  I don't need anyone to write code for me (although you can for others if you like), all I need is what topics/links I should read up on.  I should note the dotted lines come in various colors and are all either oval or linear in shape.

```
 Apparently my question is "too broad", so let me clarify.  How could I separate the dotted lines from non dotted lines in an image such as the one given here?
```

Comment: OpenCV could be your choice (edge detection, primarily): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389384/improve-contour-detection-with-opencv-python

Comment: Just some thoughts... First find all the "blobs" -- grayscale, very low threshold (basicaly black vs non-black), connected components or contours. Filter by size (drop anything too big). The dots all look quite similar, so maybe some simple pattern/template match (on grayscale or intensity, ignoring color) to filter out just the dots. Partition the dots based on color (maybe sum of absolute differences). Then try to fit a line/ellipse to each group. Eliminate outliers. More examples of what you could possibly get as input would help. May get tricky with multiple lines/ellipses of same color.

Comment: You can try image subtraction.